# How can I get auto-completion working via xrdp?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xrdp, auto-completion

I wanted to connect via xrdp from my windows 8.1 machine to my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit Server
. 
It works fine now, big fun. The only Problem I experienced is that when I want to use autocomplete via TAB it does show anything. But if I use Shift and TAB it's working. The Problem is only present under xrdp. Autocomplete is working fine via ssh and on a local screen.

I tried to alter the layout in /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini (Im sure it's the right file because I'm using a german keyboardlayout). This didn't help anyway.

Command I used: `sudo xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini`

`setxkbmap de` does not work either via xrdp. It says that this feature is not available via xrdp.

I also edited the: xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml file and changed

```
"property name=”&lt;Super&gt;Tab” type=”string” value=”switch_window_key”/"
```

to

```
"property name=”&lt;Super&gt;Tab” type=”empty”/".
```

Is autocomplete even available via xrdp? Is it customizable?

I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: Dumb question: is the keyboard definition on the server and on the client exactly the same?  (both German?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a german keyboardlayout, then the right file with your keyboard mapping is km-0407.ini, so use it:

```
sudo xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-0407.ini
```

Check the doc [here](https://www.mankier.com/8/xrdp-genkeymap). Still, in the best case scenario, this will only change your keyboard layout. This won't solve the auto-completion issues.